# Scrollbar on Text widget may require scroll before appearing based on tab order

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, ttk

The tkinter's `Scrollbar` associated with a `Text` widget doesn't always appear correctly when the `ttk.Notebook` tab that contains them is selected.

Here are two different procedures to demonstrate the strange behavior:

1. Run the program. Notice the 1st tab. Press the button, and lines are written  to the Text widget in the second tab. Go to the 2nd tab. Note the scroll bar and the scroll button w/i the scroll bar is visible.
2. Run the program a 2nd time, but this time, before pressing the button, select the 2nd tab, do nothing, then select the 1st tab again. Then press the button, then select the 2nd tab.  The Scroll button in the scroll bar is not visible.  You must put your mouse in the text widget and scroll the mouse button to see it appear.

How can I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import ttk

class Log:
    def __init__(self,nb,name):
        # Make a frame and put it on a tab
        self.frame= Frame(nb);
        nb.add(self.frame, text=name)

        # Put a scroll text on the frame
        self.scrollBar=Scrollbar(self.frame)
        self.text = Text(self.frame,
                        yscrollcommand=self.scrollBar.set,
                        width =40,
                        height=10)

        self.scrollBar.config(command=self.text.yview)

        self.text.pack(side=LEFT) 
        self.scrollBar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y) 

    def fillLog(self):
        for i in range(100):
            self.text.insert('end','hellow world\n')

root = Tk()
nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.pack()

log1 = Log(nb,'log1')
log2 = Log(nb,'log2')

ttk.Button(root, text='PUT TEXT IN 2nd tab',command=log2.fillLog).pack()

mainloop()
```

I am using Python 2.7 on Windows 7 (three computers).

[image]

Comment: For me it works as you would expect, so you might have done something wrong, check it out again.

Comment: Make sure you follow my instructions to the letter. To see the problem, start the program from scratch. Select the second tab, do nothing (nothing, don't click anywhere in the text widget or the slider) then select the first tab.  Then press the button. Then select the second tab.  You'll notice the slider is no there. It only appears when you click on the text widget and scroll with the mouse.  I've tried this many times on many computers.  I should add that I'm using Windows 7

Comment: For me it works, but I am using Python 3.5

Comment: Feel free t try it with 2.7 on windows, that would help me show the world that it's not just my imagination.  I've been putting this one off for months at work. Finally I distilled the problem to the simplest script I could come up with and put it on stackoverflow.

Comment: I have just installed Python 2.7, and it seems to work normally...it could be a problem related to your installation of Python or your OS...

Comment: Is there a way I can send a small screen shot?  Just to be sure we're talking about the same thing.  I've tried this one several computers, at home and at work.

Comment: You can add the picture to your post, what's the problem?

Comment: Upon reviewing my original description, I should have been more clear that it's the little scroll button in the scroll bar that doesn't show up in the second case. The little button you pick with you mouse and move up and down. The scroll bar itself shows up in both cases.  I have now made the changes.

Comment: The code works fine for me on OSX (though, I'm using ActivePython rather than the built-in version)

Comment: Added two screen shots

Comment: I tested your code in python 3.4 with a few modifications because of the syntax difference but it worked perfectly so maybe you would consider updating to the newer version of python?